# Application specific routing table in linux

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I've two systems `A` and `B` with different network provider but connected to the same switch.

Suppose `IP of A is 0.0.0.10` and `IP of B is 1.1.1.10`.

I can make them connect locally or over internet by just using changing to different gateway.

e.g.

At system A:

```
route add -host 1.1.1.10 gw 0.0.0.1 (to connect over internet)
route add -host 1.1.1.10 gw 0.0.0.2 (to connect locally)
```

For my testing purposes I need them to connect over internet. But i need them to connect locally only for `teamviewer`  application as over internet teamviewer is slow.

Is it possible? If yes, how to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand the underpinnings of this problem, you need to stop thinking of "one system, one IP address, magic routing".

Since they are connected to the same switch, all the difficulties go away, if you just assign both hosts another (unroutable, eg. 192.168.x) IP address, that makes them visible to each other, without assigning a gateway to those.

This can be as easy as

```
ifconfig eth0:1 192.168.168.[1|2] netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

or one of the more modern friends (like `ip ad add`)

Now a connection to the public IP address will go through the internet, while a connection to the local address will stay local.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and awesome response. Just edit `ipconfig` to `ifconfig` since it's a linux related question. :D

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup - mixing `ip ad add` and `ifconfig` in the head produces undesirable output ...

Comment: can you tell me how to add it permanently. Now upon a system restart, the system resets to the old config.

Comment: That depends on your distro - but you might want to look at /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: I've a fedora 20. There is no directory like this in /etc. Other few directory and files are there with network prefix. but nothing useful I can see.

Comment: Then you might want to look at /etc/sysconfig/networking and copy-and-adapt ifcfg-eth0 to ifcfg-etho:0. You might need to add some symlinks, google is your friend (I use debian and ubuntu)